# newtonsoft.json SerializeObject to empty string

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize different objects to json string.

```
var seetings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
        };

string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite, seetings);
```

It works for all types of objects I have tried except one. The problematic one returns json string: "[]"
Any idea what it could be? There is no error. The same result is if I remove seetings. All properties of this class are public(but it extends from abstract class with abstract properties). The value for object of empty string is: "{MyNamespace.CodeList < MyNamespace.ContentType >}" while for other objects, the value is like :"{MyNamespace.SomeClass}". What this difference exactly means?

Comment: isn't `CodeList` a class?

Comment: Please provide sample class and more information. Because By CodeList and SomeClass it is really difficult for community people to understand your problem and provide you help.

Comment: It looks like your object can be casted to `IEnumerable` and it doesn't contain any elements

Comment: You need to show an MCVE example of the problem.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `SerializeObject` is picking an undesired converter, try forcing it using the 3rd parameter:

```
JsonConverter[] converters = ... // Pick of from http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconverter.htm#fullInheritance
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite, seetings, converters);
```

Comment: I have tried all converters, like this: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite, Formatting.Indented, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.BinaryConverter()); but all converters returns the same result: "\r\n  [],\r\n  []..."

Comment: I guess the problem is that object to write has value: {MyNameSpace.CodeList<MyNameSpace.SomeType>} and type:
MyNameSpace.CodeListBase{MyNameSpace.CodeList<MyNameSpace.SomeType>} while successful convert has object of type: MyNameSpace.SomeType and value {MyNameSpace.SomeType}. Any idea?